# Passing a value from an assembly to an application in C#

Tags: c#, dll, parameter-passing

If I have an assembly which contains a function that manipulates a string and then returns that string, and I then have a separate C# application which calls the function from the assembly...

How can I pass the manipulated string from the assembly into the application?

For example, If I have this assembly...

```
using System;

namespace test
{

    public class Class1
    {
        string inputString = "hello";
        string outputString;

        public static string Convert(ref inputString, ref outputString)
        {
            outputString = inputString.ToUpper();
            return outputString;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this application which calls the Convert function within the assembly...

```
using System;
using test;

public class Class2
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Class1.Convert();
    }
}
```

How can I get the returned outputString into the Class2 application?
I can't reference it in the Main() function so how can I pass it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to pass in a valid and then return another value?  Then get rid of the of properties on your Class1, they are not necessary.  Just make the input string the parameter of the Convert function, and then return the output.

```
using System;

namespace test
{

    public class Class1
    {
        public static string Convert(string inputString)
        {
            string outputString = inputString.ToUpper();
            return outputString;
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
using System;
using test;

public class Class2
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string thisIsMyReturnedString = Class1.Convert("whatever the input value should be");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, very helpful. I should have known that.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

Your Convert() function only needs to take in *one* parameter, since you're returning the other value. The parameter shouldn't be marked as `ref` unless you're going to modify it within your function.

---

Replace:

```
Class1.Convert();
```

with

```
string inputValue = "old value";
string returnValue = Class1.Convert(ref inputValue);
```

Comment: Also, there is no need for the parameters to be reference as you only change the value of outputString but that is also the value that you are returning.

Comment: @Maess: Thanks, I must have corrected it while you were typing. :)

Comment: That was more a comment for the OP than for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add reference to your dll in the main project:

In the main project, right click References --> Add Reference
Once that is done, you can use Convert like this:

```
string result = Class1.Convert(ref myInputString, ref myOutputString);
```

On a sidenote, your return is useless, you already are using the parameters as reference.
Your method's signature should be void:

```
public static void Convert(ref inputString, ref outputString)
{
    outputString = inputString.ToUpper();
}
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
string input = "My InPuT";
string output = "";
Class1.Convert(ref input, ref output);
//Here, output = "MY INPUT"
```

Comment: +1 For code snippets && mentioning that you need to add a reference.

Answer (score 0):

If it's two different projects inside the same solution add a reference to the project. If it's two different solutions, add a reference to the dll.